Fallacy in determining the range of $f(x)=\frac{1}{4-x^2}$
In the way its taught here, finding the range of a reciprocal function like $f(x)=\frac{1}{4-x^2}$ involves the following method:

$x^2\geq0$. This implies $4-x^2\leq4$.
For $f(x)$ to be minimum, $4-x^2$ has to be maximum, which is when $x=0$. Thus, $f(x)_\text{min}=\frac{1}{4}$.
For $f(x)$ to be maximum, $4-x^2$ has to be minimum, which is when $x\rightarrow\infty$. Thus, $f(x)_\text{max}\rightarrow0$.

This is clearly flawed since the maximum value is less than the minimum value.
A similar reasoning has worked in most cases (such as, $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$). I suspect that this does not work in this case is because all the functions in which this reasoning works are always positive; or maybe this is because the function in question is both decreasing and increasing at suitable intervals?
In either case, I cannot think of a reason as to why exactly this is flawed.
Hopefully I'm allowed to go off into a tangent here by stating that, in certain problems in Physics, I have differentiated the denominator and set that to zero to find a maximum or a minimum, and then using the same logic (if denominator is maximum, the entire fraction is minimum) to obtain a correct answer.
As for obtaining the range of this function, I found the following correct method:
Let $y=\frac{1}{4-x^2}$. Making $x^2$ the subject gives $x^2=\frac{4y-1}{y}$. Since $x^2\geq0$, $\frac{4y-1}{y}\geq0$. Solving this inequality gives $y\in(-\infty,0)\cup\left(\frac{1}{4},\infty\right)$.
Why does this work, while the previous one does not?
P.S.: The syllabus is structured in such a way that we are to learn inverse functions, types of functions viz. injective, surjective, reflexive, transitive and symmetric; application of derivatives to analyze the behaviour of functions which are the parts of the next year's syllabus. I'm not sure if this lack of knowledge is the reason I am confused.

(2) and (3) are not generally true.

The inverse function approach works because the domain of the inverse is the range of the original.

@BrianMoehring Can I ask why? Why does it work for some cases and why not for others?

Because $0.5 > -0.125 \not \Rightarrow 2 < -8$

@Vasili oh... i see my confusion now

Theorem: Let $a<b,$ and $g$ be a strictly increasing function, and $h$ be a strictly decreasing function. Then $$g(a)<g(b)$$ and $$h(b)<h(a).$$
Corollary: When multiplying an inequality by a negative number, the inequality symbol must be reversed. (For example, applying the function $h,$ where $h(x)=-\frac13x:$ $\quad-3x<-12\implies x>4.)$

Since the reciprocal function $\dfrac1x$ is strictly decreasing on any negative domain and on any positive domain (though not on $\mathbb R$ as an entirety), max and min become flipped when we are taking the reciprocal of purely positive, or purely negative, values. So,

for negative $4-x^2,$ the maximum value (i.e., $0)$ indeed corresponds to the minimum value of the reciprocal (i.e., $-\infty),$ while the minimum value (i.e., $-\infty)$ indeed corresponds to the maximum value of the reciprocal (i.e., $0);$
for positive $4-x^2,$ the maximum value (i.e., $4)$ indeed corresponds to the minimum value of the reciprocal (i.e., $\dfrac14),$ while the minimum value (i.e., $0)$ indeed corresponds to the maximum value of the reciprocal (i.e., $+\infty);$
when $4-x^2$ is zero, its reciprocal is $\pm\infty.$

Hence, the range of $\dfrac{1}{4-x^2}$ is $$(-\infty,0)\cup\left[\frac14,\infty\right).$$

Your argument only works for functions that are always positive (or always negative).
The correct version for a function that can take positive and negative values should be:

For $f(x)$ to be minimum, $4-x^2$ has to be negative and as small (in modulus) as possible. It can clearly be arbitrarily close to $0$ (and negative), so the infimum is $-\infty$.

For $f(x)$ to be maximum, $4-x^2$ has to be positive  and as small (in modulus) as possible. It can clearly be arbitrarily close to $0$ (and positive), so the supremum is $+\infty$.




(in modulus)

Do I get an inequality involving modulus, if I go with this chain of arguments? Or is the second approach in my question the only valid one?

@shrihankp another way of looking at it: the maximum is the largest positive value of $f(x)$, which occurs at the smallest positive value of the denominator. The minimum is the smallest negative value of $f(x)$, which occurs at the largest negative value of the denominator.

Ah, that makes sense.

Actually let me explain you the Actual Truth.
That is generally we are given questions about this topic like
$1)$ Let $f:R-$ {$-2,2$}$\to R$ , be a function defined as $f(x)=\frac{1}{4-x^{2}}$ . Find the range of $f(x)$
Now, your Approach is correct. That is $$y=\frac{1}{4-x^{2}}$$
$$\implies y(4-x^{2})=1$$
$$\implies 4y-1=y(x^{2})$$
$$\implies x^{2}=\frac{4y-1}{y}$$
$$\implies x=\sqrt{\frac{4y-1}{y}}$$
Now the range is $(-\infty,0)\cup(\frac{1}{4},\infty)$
Because, look carefully at the question.
It is mentioned that $f: R-$ {$-2,2$} $\to R$  which implies that the domain is any real value except $-2,2$.
Now the given function is $$y=\frac{1}{4-x^{2}}$$. Which implies that the value of $y$ is always real for any value of $x$ except for $x=${$-2,2$}.
Which implies the given function is an onto function.
If the function would have been $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}}$$, then the logic would have been different
But in your question since square root is not present, so the value of $y$ is real for any value of $x$ except $x=$ {$-2,2$}.
So, the range of $f(x)$ is $(-\infty,0)\cup(\frac{1}{4},\infty)$

The range is wrong

The range includes $\left{\frac14\right}$ too, which you missed.
